# How to get a string out of x509 certificate public key in go?

Tags: go, base64, x509certificate, x509

If I have an `*x509.Certificate` object, how can I extract the public key base64 string representation out of it?

Comment: Public keys consist of more than one part (an [RSA key](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rsa/#PublicKey) is two numbers; an [EC key](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/ecdsa/#PublicKey) is a curve description plus a point on that curve), so it's not obvious what you mean by "base64 string representation". Can you add an example for the desired output to the question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NOTE: Jump to **#3** if you already have the `x509.Certificate` object.

---

You would need to do the following:

1. Decode the PEM with [`pem.Decode()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/pem/#Decode).

```golang
block, _ := pem.Decode([]byte(certPEM))
```

2. Parse the certificate with [`x509.ParseCertificate()`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/x509/#ParseCertificate).

```golang
cert, _ := x509.ParseCertificate(block.Bytes)
```

3. Marshal the Public key with [`x509.MarshalPKIXPublicKey()`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/x509/#MarshalPKIXPublicKey).

```
publicKeyDer, _ := x509.MarshalPKIXPublicKey(cert.PublicKey)
```

4. Encode it in a PEM encoded structure with [`pem.EncodeToMemory()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/pem/#EncodeToMemory).

```golang
publicKeyBlock := pem.Block{
    Type:  "PUBLIC KEY",
    Bytes: publicKeyDer,
}
publicKeyPem := string(pem.EncodeToMemory(&publicKeyBlock))
```

Run it on [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/wHYqA44DymL)

---

You can confirm the result if you copy the certificate in the example to a file `cert.pem` with the command:

```
openssl x509 -inform pem -in cert.pem -pubkey -noout
```

You should get the same result!